# How do I assign a object with specific int value?

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jpanel

I'm at the moment trying to make a game that is heavily inspired by "Adventure Capitalism" as a school-project in Java. I've made an array that holds values(temporary, will change) and I when I press a button(upgradeButton) I want an array/for to search for the right position of the array to the right position of the object.

For example, object 3 out of 5 got an upgrade to 20$ from 15$(start value). I've tried and nothing seems to work, I'm fairly new to Java, started java this September 2016. Here's my code, ask anything about it, it's a little messy but I'll clean it up once I get everything to work :) ATM I only use 1 object just to get it to work, but later on I'll re-write with list etc.

**"Investment class"**

```
public class Investments {
public int x, y, bX, bY, bWidth, bHeight, width, height, yLoad, money;
int worth[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80};
float Loading;

//String path;

//boolean ifAdd = false;

GamePanel gp;
Image invest;
ImageIcon investImage = new ImageIcon("images/image.png");

public Investments(int x, int y, int worth, float Loading) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.Loading = Loading;
    width = 64;
    height = 64;
    yLoad = 0;
    bX = x + 75;
    bY = y + 30;
    bWidth = 60;
    bHeight = 20;
}
```

**JPanel class**

```
    public GamePanel() {
    if (isRunning)
        return;

    //invest = createInvestList(8);
    invest = new Investments(30, 30, 20, 1f);
    moneyButton = new JButton("$$$"); moneyButton.setBounds(175, 61, 55, 20); add(moneyButton); moneyButton.addActionListener(this);
    upgradeButton = new JButton("^"); upgradeButton.setBounds(175, 37, 55, 20); add(upgradeButton); upgradeButton.addActionListener(this);

    this.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    addMouseListener(this);

    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}
```

**JPanel further down, button-method**

```
        if(ae.getSource() == upgradeButton){
        //what to do here? perhaps a for loop that scans the array and then attach it to the specific object? 
    }
}
```

The code is very messy, yes. As mentioned, will clean up, sorry if it's hard to read/understand. As I mentioned also, started with java this September, kind of new and I need a little help how to get the right "worth" to the right object.(worth[i] = object[3] etc)

Comment: Forgot to mention, I want to add value to the current worth. Like worth += 10; for each upgrade after I asign the right object to it etc. If that's not too much to ask for if anyone is free to help :-) Appreciate all help!

Comment: you can click on the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41026933/edit) button below your question and add more info instead of putting it in comments

Comment: @R.Andersson Take a look at my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I asign a object with specific int value?

If you are asking how to access a specific object from a collection of created objects, you can create an arraylist or an array of objects and access specific object through the arraylist index:

```
ArrayList<Investment> myInvestments = new ArrayList<Investment>();

myInvestments.add(/*write your investment object here*/);

myInvestments.get(2);             //get 3rd investment object 

myInvestments.get(2).upgrade();   //upgrade the 3rd investment object in the list
```

---

For using array:

```
Investment[] myInvestments = new Investment[20];

myInvestments[0] = new Investment();  //assign investment object to your array

myInvestments[2];                     //get 3rd investment object 

myInvestments[2].upgrade();            //upgrade the 3rd investment object in the array
```

Comment: Kind of helped me out :) Thanks! :D Got it to work, regards R.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using a Map (Map < K, V >)?https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

You can map an object to a value (or another object). So, something like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> upgradeMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
upgradeMap.put("level1", 10);
...
value += upgradeMap.get("level1");
```